# Triangulations of the Hyperbolic Plane

Tags: geometry, triangles, hyperbolic-geometry, triangulation

I'm studying triangulations of the hyperbolic plane and have come across the following theorem:

> If we are given a triangle $\Delta_0$ with angles $\pi$/l,$\pi$/m,$\pi$/n, where the
> integers l, m, n satisfy $1/l+1/m+1/n<1$, if we obtain further triangles
> by reflection in the sides of $\Delta_0$, then obtain further triangles by
> reflections in the sides of the new ones, and so on, the result is a
> set of infinitely many triangles, no two of which overlap (adjacent
> ones have common boundary points), and which together cover the entire
> hyperbolic plane. The entire structure is invariant with respect to
> each of the reflections mentioned.

There is no proof given in the text book I'm reading (although a proof of one case is given), whilst it does provide a source for the claim, I can't find the book it references. If somebody could provide a proof or point me towards a source for a proof, that would be great.

Comment: Which book is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of the Poincare polygon theorem. Typing that phrase into Google gives several hits to different people's lecture notes. You can also look it up in Ratcliffe's book [Foundations of hyperbolic manifolds](https://books.google.com/books/about/Foundations_of_Hyperbolic_Manifolds.html?id=toJhewAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description).